# include_path behaviour not working as expected

Tags: php

I've just moved a load of sites to a new VPS and have a strange problem 
with include_path. It's something that worked fine on the old server but 
not on the new.

I'll try and explain it using a simple example...

In `/home/kin/www/lib/Zend` and also in `/home/kin/www/ipb/_membadmin/Zend`
there is a file called `test1.php` which simply echoes which folder it is in.

In `/home/kin/www/ipb/_membadmin` there is a file called `test.php`
It has one line....

```
require_once 'Zend/test1.php';
```

When you run it, as you would expect, it echoes the line from `test1.php` in 
`/home/kin/www/ipb/_membadmin/Zend`

If you then rename `/home/kin/www/ipb/_membadmin/Zend` to something else (so 
the 'include' statement can't find it), and run `test.php` again, it SHOULD 
(I think) echo the file in `/home/kin/www/lib/Zend` because php include_path 
is set to include `/home/kin/public_html/lib` (which `phpinfo.php` confirms).
... but it doesn't.

Why not? If there is an include path of `/home/kin/public_html/lib` then 
surely

```
require_once 'Zend/test1.php';
```

should point to `/home/kin/www/lib/Zend`. It does on the old server!

I must be missing something obvious but I don't know what!

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: could you please give us the contents of `get_include_path()` on both cases, and the output

Comment: Interesting. If I run get_include_path() on the new server, I get

Comment: Interesting. If I run get_include_path() on the new server, I get
.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/public_html/lib  

but if I run phpinfo from the same place, the 'core' section reports include_path as  
.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/kin/public_html/lib

On the old server, both get_include_path and phpinfo report /home/kin/public_html/lib  

So why is the new server missing the 'kin' out of the path??

Answer (score 0):

After the diagnostic you just gave it now seems clear that something is overriding the environment path.

There has to be some line in your code where the set_include_path is getting called. Is any Zend specific code running that you haven't checked? That missing directory clearly paints the culprit as a rogue `set_include_path()`

Comment: I will check - but it's exactly the same code on the new server just copied over from the old one!

Comment: this is indeed strange. I'm not very experienced in analyzing configuration issues. I must admit I'm stumped, the only other avenue is to check php.ini and to see if things are set correctly, but I think you did that already T.T. This is the only other way to set path `ini_set('include_path', '/usr/lib/pear');` other than that, I'm out of cards

Comment: Thanks for the ideas anyway. At least I now know roughly where the problem lies even if not what's causing it!